# resolving promise, stil then of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I think im resolving the promise put the code is still saying then of undefined, its not returning the promise, why?

```
export const SpacesPutImage = (folder, file, id, data, expertId, avatarUrl) => {

    console.log(folder, file, id, data, expertId, avatarUrl)
    if (avatarUrl === undefined) {
        console.log('si')
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            apiCall('put', `/api/experts/${expertId}/spaces`, {
                    data: data,
                    size: file.size,
                    id: id,
                    folder: folder,
                    fileType: file.type
                })
                .then((res) => resolve(res.Location))
                .catch(err => reject(err))


        })
    } else {
        console.log('no')
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            apiCall('put', `/api/experts/${expertId}/spaces/${avatarUrl.split("/")[4]}`, {
                    data: data,
                    size: file.size,
                    id: expertId,
                    folder: folder,
                    fileType: file.type
                }).then((res) => resolve(res.Location))
                .catch(err => reject(err))
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post real error message and possibly apiCall function if possible.

Comment: Wrapping `apiCall()` in `new Promise` is an anti-pattern since `apiCall()` itself returns a promise

Comment: Are you awaiting the returned promise correctly? Is the error occurring on the result from spacesPutImage?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need `new Promise`, just return the api call, if it uses `.then` and `.catch` it means that it's already a promise.

```
export const SpacesPutImage = (folder, file, id, data, expertId, avatarUrl) => {
    console.log(folder, file, id, data, expertId, avatarUrl)
    if (avatarUrl === undefined) {
        console.log('si')
        return apiCall('put', `/api/experts/${expertId}/spaces`, {
            data: data,
            size: file.size,
            id: id,
            folder: folder,
            fileType: file.type
        }).then(res => res.Location)       
    } else {
        console.log('no')
        return apiCall('put', `/api/experts/${expertId}/spaces/${avatarUrl.split("/")[4]}`, {
            data: data,
            size: file.size,
            id: expertId,
            folder: folder,
            fileType: file.type
         }).then(res => res.Location)
    }
}
```

Please, also add to your question what is `apiCall` and where do you call `SpacesPutImage`.

> I think im resolving the promise put the code is still saying then of undefined

Please provide the correct error and probably where it happens.

One thing that can be happing, as said in the comments is that `apiCall` doesn't return a promise and `saying then of undefined` can be about `apiCall` not returning a promise.

Comment: Doesn't explain why OP gets `undefined`

Comment: _"if it uses `.then` and `.catch` it means that it's already a promise."_ But that's the problem of OP's code, `apiCall` doesn't return a promise, which would explain the "`.then` of undefined" error.

Comment: @EmileBergeron that is a good point. OP's question have too many missing parts and it's hard to understand, it doesn't even show the correct error. But that is a good observation!

Comment: @charlietfl `Would throw error` and that is probably the error that the OP is getting

Comment: Could also be as simple as there is no `Location` property on `res`. Just not enough known

Comment: Im sorry, know that i read it, its less clear. ApiCall is just a handler that returns a value, and i call SpacesPutImage here

Comment: @SvenBrodersen please provide `apiCall` function in your question. this `ApiCall is just a handler that returns a value` is to vague

Comment: @SvenBrodersen ok but you wrote it as if `apiCall()` returns a promise not a value leaving evryone to guess at what actual error and problem is